# Angular jasmine how to spy an async spy method

Tags: typescript, jasmine, angular11

I am new to writing test with async/await in angular.
I have the following code. The service method is an async method. The test fails saying component.options.length is 0.

Can anyone please help me how to fix the error so the options has got the value i set in spy?

Thanks

spec.ts

```
spySideNavService = jasmine.createSpyObj('SideNavService', [], {
            setOrgUserDetails: () => {},
            loadMenus: () =>
                [
                    {
                        id: 'my-menu',
                        label: 'My Menu',
                        icon: 'far fa-envelope fa-2x',
                        url: 'url'
                    }
                ] as NavOption[]
        });
        
    describe('ngOnInit', () => {
        it('should add navigation options', () => {
            expect(component.options.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
        });
    });
```

component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.options = await this.sideNavService.loadMenus();   
}
```

SideNavService:

```
async loadMenus(): Promise<NavOption[]> {
//logic
}
```

Tried answer given below but still not working:

```
describe('ngOnInit', () => {
    it('should add navigation options', fakeAsync(() => {
        // !! call tick(); to tell the test to resolve all promises
        // before coming to my expect line
        tick();
        expect(component.options.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `fakeAsync/tick` to control promises.

```
// !! add fakeAsync
it('should add navigation options', fakeAsync(() => {
            // !! call tick(); to tell the test to resolve all promises
            // before coming to my expect line
            // !! call ngOnInit
            component.ngOnInit();
            console.log(component.options);
            tick();
            console.log(component.options);
            expect(component.options.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
        }));
```

Before, the test would go to the `await` line and go back to the test for the `expect` because the `await` is saying to do this later. Now with the `tick`, we are saying if they are any promises created, resolve them before moving forward.

Also, I think you're missing a `Promise.resolve` on `loadMenus`.

```
loadMenus: () => Promise.resolve(
                [
                    {
                        id: 'my-menu',
                        label: 'My Menu',
                        icon: 'far fa-envelope fa-2x',
                        url: 'url'
                    }
                ] as NavOption[])
```

I am thinking the `Promise.resolve` is required so it can be `await`ed.

*edit*
I don't think the `done` callback will help you.

You can try using `await fixture.whenStable()` to wait for the promise(s). Try this:

```
describe('ngOnInit', () => {
    it('should add navigation options', async () => {
        component.ngOnInit();  
        await fixture.whenStable();
        expect(component.options.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @AliF50. But still test is failing. "NavigationComponent > ngOnInit > should add navigation options"
Error: Expected 0 to be greater than 0.

Comment: Check out my edit with explicitly calling `ngOnInit` and logging out the `component.options`. The first log should hopefully give you `[]` and the next log should give you the 1 entry. If that doesn't work, I am not sure what the issue can be.

Comment: No, this didn't work either. the component.options length is always 0

Comment: i saw somethign similar to this, but not sure how to make the change to my need. Can you please help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59732836/how-can-i-let-jasmine-wait-for-a-promise-to-be-resolved-or-rejected

Comment: I don't think the `done` can help you in this regard. Try with `await fixture.whenStable()`. I have shown it in the edit.